# Как получить время сотового оператора?

Tags: время, android

Добрый день!
Хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли получить вермя сотового оператора без наличия интернета на устройстве?

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет изучение того, как это сделано в платформе:

[`https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/services/java/com/android/server/NetworkTimeUpdateService.java`][1]



  [1]:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/services/java/com/android/server/NetworkTimeUpdateService.java

Comment: @mantigatos там используются классы не доступные в обычных приложениях